# Error Running Tensorflow with XLA

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to run a simple tensorflow example using JIT compilation, as shown in https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/experimental/xla/jit . Instead of the mnist_softmax_xla sample, I'm using the following code:

```
def main(_):
    config = tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True)
    jit_level = 0 
    if FLAGS.xla:
        # Turns on XLA JIT compilation.
        jit_level = tf.OptimizerOptions.ON_1

    config.graph_options.optimizer_options.global_jit_level = jit_level
    # Creates a session with log_device_placement set to True.
    with tf.Session(config=config) as sess:
        # Creates a graph.
        with tf.device('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:XLA_CPU:0'):
            a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
            b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2], name='b')
            c = tf.matmul(a, b)

        # Runs the op.
        print(sess.run(c))
```

I'm getting an error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Cannot assign a device to node 'MatMul': Could not satisfy explicit device specification '/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:XLA_CPU:0' because no devices matching that specification are registered in this process; available devices: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
     [[Node: MatMul = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false, transpose_b=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:XLA_CPU:0"](a, b)]]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Official binaries don't come with XLA enabled. You have to build from source, or reuse the XLA binary someone else built (ie, from https://github.com/yaroslavvb/tensorflow-community-wheels)

Comment: I work with her. She is building TF with XLA by doing `<Other options> TF_ENABLE_XLA=1 ./configure`

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was running with Python2. It now works when running with Python3